# ¿Como usar argumento opcional en consulta eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo esta funcion, que me arroja los productos mas vendidos, quiero implementar que tambien se puedan filtrar atraves del mes y año, pero ademas que estos 2 parametros sean opcionales, si la funcion recibe alguno de estos parametros (o ambos) realize la consulta utilizandolos, pero sino que realize la consulta usando el mes y año actual:

```
public function BestSellerProducts($limit, $year=null, $month=null){
        $products = Product::select('products.id','products.name', DB::raw('sum(productables.quantity) as totalcantidad'))
        ->join('productables','productables.product_id','=','products.id')
        ->whereIn('productable_type', [Order::class])
        ->join('orders','orders.id','=','productables.productable_id')

        ->whereYear('orders.created_at','=',date("Y"))
        ->whereMonth('orders.created_at','=',date("m"))

        ->orderBy('totalcantidad','desc')
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->limit($limit);
        // dd(date("m"));
        dd($products->get());
        return $products->get();
    }
```

Mi pregunta es como decirle a la funcion, "si recibes este parametro usalo, sino, utiliza la funcion date() para obtener el dato", quiero evitar usar un if al principio preguntando si year o month es null, porque tendria que repetir casi todo el codigo (No me deja escribir un if dentro de la consulta eloquent). Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Agrega aquello que hayas  intentado por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función when, en la que asignas una variable que te permita entrar a una función

```
$isYear = !is_null($year);
$isMonth =!is_null($month);

...
->join('orders','orders.id','=','productables.productable_id')
->when($isYear, function ($query) {
    $query->whereYear('orders.created_at','=',date("Y"));
})
->when($isMonth, function ($query) {
    $query->whereMonth('orders.created_at','=',date("m"));
})
...
```