# Recibir 2 variables en funcion ->when query builder Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

hace un tiempo [formule una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/486539/como-usar-argumento-opcional-en-consulta-eloquent) sobre como hacer cierta consulta con un query builder cuando un parametro es recibido y si no, que no la haga, alguien me respondio que podia utilizar la funcion "`when`" de laravel, me funciono correctamente, pero con el tiempo me vi en la obligacion de utilizar 2 variables, donde ambas tienen que llegar para hacer funcionar la query, intente utilizar un "`&&`" y aparentemente funciona, luego intente utilizar un "`and`" enves de "`&&`" y aparentemente igual funciona:

```
$isStartDate = !is_null($start_date);
$isEndDate = !is_null($end_date);
->when($isStartDate and $end_date, function ($query) use($start_date, $end_date){
            $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(orders.created_at)'),[$start_date,$end_date]);
        }
```

la syntaxis es correcta? cual deberia utilizar? no pude encontrar un ejemplo con 2 parametros en la documentacion. Gracias!

Comment: Es cuestión de gustos, a mi me gusta mas usar &&, tambien implica precedencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por la precedencia de operadores. En este caso no ves diferencia porque no se está haciendo otra operación además del `AND` o el `&&`.

Por ejemplo, si tienes algo como:

```
$valor = TRUE && FALSE;
```

y

```
$valor = TRUE and FALSE;
```

En el primer caso, `$valor` vale `FALSE`, porque primero se hace la operación `&&` (que es falso) y luego eso se le asigna a `$valor` (`&&` tiene mayor precedencia que `=`).

En el segundo caso, `$valor` vale `TRUE`, porque primero se hace la asignación `$valor = TRUE` y luego se compara con el `FALSE` de la derecha, pero no hace nada con eso porque la asignación ya se había hecho (`=` tiene mayor precedencia que `and`).